# Is it possible to send ether from contract address to my account address using the CloseChannel() function and what will be the Truffle command?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, truffle

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract exchange {
    mapping (address => uint256) public balances;
    event PaymentDone(string s);

    function Channel( uint value) payable {
        balances[msg.sender] -=value;
        balances[this] +=value;
    }

    function CloseChannel( address to,uint value) {
        if (to.send(value)) {
            PaymentDone("Done");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. I renamed a lot of stuff while I worked it out.

This contract accepts ETH deposits and keeps track of who deposited. it holds the ETH. Then, it lets the depositors withdraw to themselves, or transfer to someone else. It doesn't let depositors overdraw their accounts.

No testing, so no warranty ;-)

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract Exchange {

    mapping (address => uint256) public balances;

    event LogDeposit(address sender, uint amount);
    event LogWithdrawal(address receiver, uint amount);
    event LogTransfer(address sender, address to, uint amount);

    function deposit() payable returns(bool success) {
        balances[msg.sender] +=msg.value;
        LogDeposit(msg.sender, msg.value);
        return true;
    }

    function withdraw(uint value) returns(bool success) {
        if(balances[msg.sender] < value) throw;
        balances[msg.sender] -= value;
        msg.sender.transfer(value);
        LogWithdrawal(msg.sender, value);
        return true;
    }

    function transfer(address to, uint value) returns(bool success) {
        if(balances[msg.sender] < value) throw;
        balances[msg.sender] -= value;
        to.transfer(value);
        LogTransfer(msg.sender, to, value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Almost forgot. To withdraw from the above example, Truffle syntax would look something like:

```
var exchange;
Exchange.deployed().then(function(instance) { exchange = instance; });

var amount = 10; // for example
exchange.withdraw(amount); // a good start, but look into promises and .then
```

Hope it helps.